# how do i prepare crontab for two tests to run interchangably if the test last two days

Tags: jenkins, cron

My idea was to prepare crontab to run every four days on days divisible by four and other one to run every four days but on days divisible by 2 and 4, but I have no clue how to do that

Comment: There is no way to configure cron using [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), which is a unix tool to do that. There also no way to do that in [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax), which uses the same cron syntax and logic. What you can do is create a jenkins job with a conditional step in the language of your choice that figures out the math for you, shedule that job to run daily and if the criteria are met, kicks off the other job. ps:all days divisible by 4 are also divisible by 2. Math is strange that way.

Comment: Also,, you should reword both your summary and body to be more clear (ie: "except for", not "but").